# Taxonomy and views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

Please excuse my English.

I create a vocabulary(category), with parents and childrens:

```
Games
-futbol
-tennis
Contruct
-home
...
...
```

Add a menu for this, after, create a content type (object), with field for select a taxonomy child, with hierarchical_select module.

The url of taxonomy pages are `"taxonomy/term/X"`, for childrens and parents.

I create a view for list all the objects of the same children category,with put contextual filter "Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)" and url of this view is `"taxonomy/term/%"`.

The list is correct, i push in tennis for example, and can see the objects of this category.

The problem:

This view, modify children and parent page, I need change only the children, and afterwards make other view for parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Taxonomy Views Integrator](https://drupal.org/project/tvi) can help. It allows you to select specific views to render related content on taxonomy term pages.

This can help too I think : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82059/taxonomy-term-pages-with-multiple-views

Good luck